# Sum of product of (3i - 2)/(5i)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been struggling trying to figure this one out... Maple and Wolfram both tell me the sum i'm looking at is equal to the cuberoot of 5/2, here's the symbols:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{3i-2}{5i} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{2}}$$ But I am clueless as to why or how this is true... Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

edit help from Thomas Andrews and GFauxPas.

Comment: Well, one thing to know is that an empty product is defined to be $1$, and so you can change the left side to $\sum_{n=0}^n\cdots$ and remove the $-1$ from the right. Might make a power series approach clear.

Comment: "The answer to my question", what is your question?

Comment: @GFauxPas: My question was what that sum summed to; now I want to know how to get that with a computer algebra system just spitting it out to me.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thanks, I'll edit it!

Comment: Do you know the Binomial Theorem for fractional exponents? (If not, try just cubing each side using the [Cauchy product](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: 
I think if you expand the power series for: $$f(x)=(1-x)^{-1/3}$$ around $0$, and then evaluate at  $x=\frac{3}{5}$, you'll get your result.

The power series for $f$ is, $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^n}{n!} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{3i-2}{3}\right)$$

And:

$$\frac{x^n}{n!} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{3i-2}{3} =\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{x(3i-2)}{3i}$$

Comment: You forgot the $\frac{1}{n!}$, which is necessary to get the denominator of the answer to be $5i$ rather than $5$.  But yes, this is a nice solution.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkFischler Fixed.